# Como fazer postagem numa página do facebook utilizando PHP

Tags: php, facebook

Gostaria de saber como fazer postagens automáticas em uma determinada página do facebook utilizando PHP. Consultei a documentação que o facebook disponibiliza e além de estar em inglês também não entendi o suficiente para montar o script. Já tenho o AppId e o AppSecret.

Documentação consultada: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/4.0.0?locale=pt_BR

Att.

Comment: Poste aqui até onde você foi, qual foi sua duvida na documentação ?

Comment: Não parece ampla, me parece uma questão razoável. Ele está simplesmente perguntando como "postar em uma página do facebook usando PHP" o qual ele tem acesso.

Comment: Na página que você postou tem um link para um exemplo em PHP que é o que você quer e mais um pouco.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Aqui está o código que você precisa para compartilhar um link para Facebook usando PHP. Com pequenas mudanças você pode usar este código para deixar apenas uma mensagem (sem link), ou fazer upload de uma foto em um álbum do Facebook. Agora sobre deixar automático...Utilize a velha e boa lógica do JavaScript!

```
<?php
// requer Facebook PHP SDK
// veja: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/gettingstarted/
require_once("/SEU_PATH_TO/facebook_php_sdk/facebook.php");

// initialize Facebook class using your own Facebook App credentials
// see: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/gettingstarted/#install
$config = array();
$config['appId'] = 'SEU_APP_ID';
$config['secret'] = 'SEU_APP_SECRET';
$config['fileUpload'] = false; // opcional

$fb = new Facebook($config);

// definindo os parâmetros do POST (substitua os valores)
$params = array(
  "access_token" => "SEU_TOKEN", // veja: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/
  "message" => "Estou usando auto post com #php #facebook",
  "link" => "http://qualquer.br",
  "picture" => "http://i.imgur.com/lHkOsiH.png",
  "name" => "Auto post com PHP",
  "caption" => "www.qualquer.com.br",
  "description" => "Automaticamente postar no Facebook com PHP usando Facebook PHP SDK."
);

// post para Facebook
// veja: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-api/
try {
  $ret = $fb->api('/SEU_FACEBOOK_ID/feed', 'POST', $params);
  echo 'Postado no face!';
} catch(Exception $e) {
  echo $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

**Configurações:**

- Você tem que renovar Token de Acesso após o vencimento (cerca de 60 dias).
- Você tem que obter o seu ID do Facebook, ou para o seu perfil pessoal ou para sua Fan Pages ou Páginas Negócios.
- Você tem que criar um aplicativo do Facebook , a fim de usar o Facebook API

Comment: Ótimo, muito obrigado, é isso mesmo. Funcionou perfeitamente, só está ocorrendo um erro de autenticação, mas isso é algo que tenho que fazer no facebook "(#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action". O importante é que o código que você passou funciona. Muito obrigado.

Comment: As postagens estão sendo feitas com o meu nome de usuário do facebook, porém eu gostaria que a postagem fosse feita com o nome da página no qual sou administrador ao invés do meu usuário. Seria possível?

Comment: `Primeiro:` Poderia marcar como resolvida? `Segundo:` Você pode sim utilizar a postagem com o nome da página, caso utilize todas as informações de sua página, tal como **FACEBOOK_ID**

Comment: Entendo, obrigado. Na linha "$ret = $fb->api('/id_da_pagina/feed', 'POST', $params);" coloco o id da página porém está publicando com o meu nome de usuário ainda. Você saberia me dizer como posso solucionar isso para publicar no nome da página? Att.

Comment: Estou utilizando conforme seu código e a publicação cai como publicações de visitantes na página e não como se fosse postado pelo facebook. Já viu isso acontecer ?