# Postar na Fanpage do facebook com PHP

Tags: php, facebook

Boa tarde. Gostaria de realizar a seguinte ação: quando alguém cadastrar um produto no meu site, gostaria que o mesmo produto fosse cadastrado na minha *Fanpage* do facebook. Já criei o aplicativo, peguei o *id* e a senha,
mas ainda sim não consigo fazer funcionar. Ele retorna um erro de autenticação e
o código que estou usando é similar ao do link abaixo:

[Como fazer postagem numa página do facebook utilizando PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/51172/como-fazer-postagem-numa-p%C3%A1gina-do-facebook-utilizando-php)

O erro apresentado é esse:

```
Graph returned an error: Invalid OAuth access token.
```

Alguém pode me orientar?

Answer (score 0):

Vi algumas soluções no stackoverflow em inglês, veja se é útil para você:

[Facebook PHP SDK - Graph returned an error: Invalid OAuth access token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33867590/facebook-php-sdk-graph-returned-an-error-invalid-oauth-access-token)

[Facebook SDK v5 Graph returned an error: Invalid OAuth access token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38342820/facebook-sdk-v5-graph-returned-an-error-invalid-oauth-access-token)

[Facebook PHP SDK access token issue when retrieve User Profile via the Graph API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32738697/facebook-php-sdk-access-token-issue-when-retrieve-user-profile-via-the-graph-api)

Comment: eu li mas não faço ideia de como gerar este token ainda ;(

Comment: sua aplicação já está publica? quando eu fiz algo envolvendo api do facebook tive que publica-la primeiro, da uma lida aqui:

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens

Comment: sim já publiquei e foi aprovada tbm tenho o id e a senha ok. so falta esse token de acesso que não sei onde gera nem como.